# Software for controlling microscope's camera's capture time and duration

Tags: video, camera, video-recording

I want to record my sample put under a microscope at various time points. So I want a video recording from the microscope's camera at odd timings like 3 A.M. in the morning and every hour since then for 5 minutes.

So I need a software which can speak to my microscope's camera and switch it on for the timings I specify.

I have a PointGrey and ProgRes C3 microscope, either of which I could use.

Comment: Pt Gry has their own software for this doesnt it ?